# Odd characters instead of apostrophes appearing with url variable (GET)

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am working on an audio player that has a popout function. I couldn't think of any way to pass the information to the resulting popout window but passing them as GET variables through the URL.

as a result, I end up with a javascript link more or less like:

```
<div id="audio-player-popout" onclick="window.open('http://popout-url/index.php?file=Filename.mp3&title=Title",'audioplayer','location=0,menubar=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=350,height=450');">
```

The problem is that when the title contains an apostrophe, it shows up as

> â€™

rather than an apostrophe. I am using php's addslashes but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Without addslashes, it causes an error with the javascript obviously.

Is there a better way to go about this or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `urlencode` on the title.

Comment: @Josh - absolutely perfect, thank you. Can you post this as an answer so I can choose it as the correct one? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the title.

From the PHP Manual:

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_.
>   have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits
>   and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs.